# A multi-threaded version of TaskScheduler such that it guarantees that higher priority task never starts execution after a lower priority task in java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I need to write a multi threaded version of TaskSchedular

```
TaskScheduler {
   TaskScheduler(List<Task> tasks)
    .... 
}


   interface Task {
      int getPriority()
      void execute()
    }
```

so that it guarantees the higher priority task never starts execution after lower priority.

Here is my single threaded version example. I need to create this multi threaded.

```
public class SingleThreadedTaskScheduler {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    private PriorityQueue<Task> taskQueue;
    private static final PriorityComparator PRIORITY_COMPARATOR = new PriorityComparator();


    public SingleThreadedTaskScheduler(List<Task> tasks){
        this.taskQueue = new PriorityQueue<Task>(tasks.size(), PRIORITY_COMPARATOR);
        this.taskQueue.addAll(tasks);
    }

    public void executeAllByPriority(){
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (Task task : taskQueue) {
                    task.execute();
                }
            }
        });

    }


    public void executeAllByPriorityWithUnInterruptableFirst(){
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PriorityQueue<Task> interruptedQueue = new PriorityQueue<Task>(taskQueue.size(),PRIORITY_COMPARATOR);
                for (Task task : taskQueue) {
                    if (task instanceof Interruptible && ((Interruptible) task).isInterrupted() ){
                        interruptedQueue.add(task);
                    } else {
                        task.execute();
                    }
                }

                for (Task task : interruptedQueue ){
                    task.execute();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Little code will help a lot.

Comment: You would have deadlock, or rather starvation..

Comment: why? U mean one thread will stuck then all will be waiting for others. In that case timeout can also be helpful.

Comment: Apart from the starvation pointed out by Sotirios, have you made any effort to solve the problem. Asking for code without putting forth any effort is generally considered inappropriate on SO.

Comment: The way you describe the operation, if you execute a task with priority 10 and it completes, you shouldn't be able to execute any other tasks if they priority 10+.

Comment: I can have my own priority. And I want to execute threads in that order.

Comment: Then you aren't asking the right question. Consider looking into `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: @Jim Garrison how do u know I din't put efforts on this. I have tried to implement this by using CyclicBarrier and CountDownLatch. But Dint come up with clean solution. IF you don't like answer, u can simply ignore and go ahead.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis for Single threaded application I used priority queue but for multi threaded version, that doest help

Comment: There exists a `PriorityBlockingQueue`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis See my example code above for single threaded solution. PBQ can ensure poll in that order. what if I want execute method of Task class in that order?

Comment: Just put your tasks in the queue which uses a custome comparator that you create and have multiple Threads poll the queue and execute them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured out the solution by myself. I am using thread pool size of 10. And using AtomicInteger to actually see if higher prority thread doesn't get CPU cycle after lower priority thread.

Please add your feedback if something you see incorrect.

```
public class MultiThreadedTaskScheduler  {

      AtomicInteger priorityCounter = new AtomicInteger(-1);
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

private PriorityQueue<Task> taskQueue;
private static final PriorityComparator PRIORITY_COMPARATOR = new PriorityComparator();


        public MultiThreadedTaskScheduler(List<Task> tasks){
            this.taskQueue = new PriorityQueue<Task>(tasks.size(), PRIORITY_COMPARATOR);
            this.taskQueue.addAll(tasks);
        }

        public void executeAllByPriority(){
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (Task task : taskQueue) {
                        executeMethod(task);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    private void executeMethod(Task task) {
        if (task.getPriority()  > priorityCounter.get() ){
            task.execute();
            priorityCounter.getAndSet(task.getPriority());
        }

    }



        public void executeAllByPriorityWithUnInterruptableFirst(){
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    PriorityQueue<Task> interruptedQueue = new PriorityQueue<Task>(taskQueue.size(),PRIORITY_COMPARATOR);
                    for (Task task : taskQueue) {
                        if (task instanceof Interruptible && ((Interruptible) task).isInterrupted() ){
                            interruptedQueue.add(task);
                        } else {
                            executeMethod(task);
                        }
                    }

                    for (Task task : interruptedQueue ){
                        executeMethod(task);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            super.finalize();
            executorService.shutdown();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused with your question. Do you want to execute lower priority task first?

I think if you are asking how to use the TaskScheduler for making sure higher priority task over lower priority and BY-Pass the default FIFO, then you need to use a PriorityBlockingQueue with an object that has implemented java.util.Comparator Interface. With your own comparator, you can also define your own priority.

Comment: I want higher priority should not get executed once any lower executes.

Comment: The way priority works in java, it relies on thread yielding logic. So, if a lower priority thread is under execution, then it will be yielded for a higher priority task. For your lower priority task to still finish and not yield, check the priority of currently executed task (try setting up catches for interrupts) and lower the currently scheduled higher priority task temporarily lower that the ones which is getting executed. Use Future with ExecutionCompletionService. You wont find many ways to achieve your goal, but in today's parallelism, priority is becoming less important.

Comment: what If I want to implement my priority instead of relying of Thread's priority. See my description above. I have my own version of priority.

Comment: If you would start using Fork/join, thread priorities become almost irrelevant since all usable cores are used for the purpose and by default your thread pool size is not greater than number of processor cores available. If you change that, then you will see a lot of CPU blocking for high number of tasks. Try not using priority, but like I said above, PriorityBlockingQueue can be your solution.

Comment: Yes, with using comparator + PriorityBlockingQueue , you can define your own priority. Refer to my answer above.

Comment: Say I have PriorityBlockingQueue. I can simply poll in certain order but if I have execute method in Task then that can't run in certain order.

Comment: To a PriorityBlockingQueue, you can submit a task with either Comparator OR Comparable. This object will carry your priority and thus your logic of prioritization. Check the JAVADOc for PriorityBlockingQueue, it will become more clear.

Comment: Putting task in priorityQueue is not a an issue but how can I ensure that if lower priority threads gets executed then any higher thread will not get CPU cycle to execute.

Comment: You are actually trying to achieve reverse priority and not sure how will you tell the language/CPU that you are actually setting a lower priority and still assign someway to not yield it. what is the use of higher priority then? Use the default FIFO for ThreadPoolExecutor or you can use FJP constructor that defines FIFO and not assign any priority to the thread. This way, your first thread executes first. I guess I dint understand your task purpose properly